# Algolia Insight Library - timestamp must not be in the future

Tags: algolia

Under insights api logs, some events are failed to log with 422 error code and in details it says "timestamp must not be in the future",Insights library is configured like below in Android application

```html
 Insights.Configuration configuration =
                new Insights.Configuration(5000, 5000, userToken);
        Insights insights = Insights.register(GoldenScentApp.getAppContext(), AppConstants.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
                AppConstants.ALGOLIA_KEY, indexName, configuration);
        insights.setMinBatchSize(1);
```

The event was logged with time GMT: Monday, 31 May 2021 06:03:07.048 but the time in Algolia Received at:2021-05-31T06:01:13.859Z

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with algolia sdk. They send old event every time new event send. Like user click event it goes in to local db. Once 10 events limit reach they send event. So in case user send 9 event in one session; then open app after 4 day when another event log algolia will send other events too. But timestamp will be older so they log as error in algolia.

work around : Solution: Set event flushDelay to 5 sec instead of 30 second which in documentation mention as 30 min(idk why).